# How do i convert webdriver.WebElement to protractor ElementFinder?

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I used browser.driver.findElements to find an element which returns WebElement but i need to convert it to ElementFinder. How would i do?

Comment: Can you show your use case ? Probably you should use `element()` resp. `element.all()`  instead of `browser.findElements()`. Other than that, Most of things which you can do with `ElementFinder` can also directly be done using `WebElement`

Answer (score 0):

Import protractor function and try to make changes by referring to below code.

`import { $, $$} from 'protractor';`

```
`ElementName`: protractor.ElementFinder = $('`element`');
`ArrayElement`: protractor.ElementArrayFinder = element.all(by.xpath('`locators`'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.id("locator"));
```

with

```
element(by.id("locator"));
```

And do the same with all locators.